# Как вывести связанный блок на всю ширину за пределы контейнера?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, шорткод

Есть у меня магазин на wordpress+woocommerce. На странице товара хочу вывести карусель с похожими товарами, но не в бутстраповском контейнере темы, а на всю ширину страницы. Какую бы позицию я не задавал для функции стандартного хука

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_main_content', 'woocommerce_output_related_products');
```

все равно похожие товары выводятся в пределах контейнера. Если я прописываю шорткод в футере, то как я понимаю здесь нет привязки к конкретному товару и при таком способе похожих товаров выводится мало (даже не хватает заполнить всю ширину страницы)..

```
<?php if (is_product()); ?>  
<section class="related-products">
   <?php echo do_shortcode ('[related_products per_page="4"]'); ?>
</section>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Т.е. грубо говоря: если выводить хуком, то выводятся все (скажем 8 похожих товаров), но в контейнере,  а если шорткодом, то уже на всю ширину, но только 2 - вот в чем дилемма..Как же быть?

Comment: наверно через js подключить php-сценарий : примерно так : var link = <?php echo $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];?>;
 т.е вы на css создаёте after block а в js в него вставляете нужное содержимое , можно на чистом js создать элемент с z-index ниже основного блока создать и в js вставить php обработчик , а вот и статейка про это http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115310/how-to-add-a-class-to-dom-element-in-javascript

Comment: вот статья на :http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createattribute.asp

Comment: @LenovoID спасибо, но покопался глубже в коде и нашел решение гораздо проще)

Answer (score 2):

Вообщем, в моем случае нашел решение более простое - отыскал хук за который получилось зацепиться:

```
add_action('footer_in_top_part','woocommerce_output_related_products',5);
```

Может быть кому-нить пригодится

Comment: это в смысле вы так реализовали ?

Comment: @LenovoID да, только хук `footer_in_top_part` вложенный и подозреваю, что не нативный, поэтому и написал в моем случае, но принцип такой, что нужно искать хуки близ футера например как здесь

Comment: а покажите пожалуйста пример , как реализовано - сайт в сети